# Корректность выражения "с улыбкой на лице"

Tags: фраза, грамотность

*Она уснула с улыбкой на лице.*

Допустимо ли выражение ***с улыбкой на лице*** или можно написать только ***с улыбкой на губах***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если опираться на статистику употребления, то, вообще говоря, "с улыбкой на лице" употребляется заметно чаще чем "с улыбкой на губах". В этом легко убедиться как если просто поискать на гугле или яндексе по общему числу вхождений, так и на специфическом сайте.

[image]

[image]

То же самое касается альтернативных форм `с улыбкою на губах/устах` и `с улыбкою на лице`. То же самое касается пар фраз типа "улыбка не сходила с его лица" / "улыбка не сходила с его губ". В общем, не будет натяжкой сказать, что улыбка в русском словоупотреблении воспринимается в больше степени как атрибут лица, а не губ.

Comment: Это даже логично, ведь человек обычно улыбается не только губами. Даже говорят иногда "он улыбнулся одними губами"

Answer (score 5):

Улыбка проявляется у людей по-разному и может различаться для разных частей лица в зависимости от ситуации или зависеть от индивидуальных особенностей человека. Можно вспомнить, что у лермонтовского Печорина *глаза* не смеялись, когда он сам смеялся. Поэтому "... на лице" можно считать нейтральным и вполне приемлемым выражением.

Answer (score 5):

Я в таких случаях как правило в [Google N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%81%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%2C%D1%81%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3) обращаюсь:
[image: Статистика употребления выражений в русскоязычных текстах]
Как видно---улыбка на лице куда более популярна в текстах. По крайней мере в рамках корпуса книг Google.

Comment: интересно, что в прошлом (нужно вбить в старой орфографии) эти формы употреблялись сопоставимо часто -  https://goo.gl/yXpSTw